# 友達のメールアドレスを知りたいです。何と言いますか。 メールアドレス、聞いてもいい？

Tags: meaning

Can someone explain/confirm what these 2 sentence structures actually means:

> 1. [話す人の動作 ]　お聞きしたいんですが。

My interpretation: I would like to listen? or is it : I would like to ask?

> 2. 友達のメールアドレスを知りたいです。何と言いますか。
>    メールアドレス、聞いてもいい？

My interpretation: Can you let me listen to what your mail address is? or is it: Is it ok for me to ASK what your mail address is?

Comment: https://jisho.org/word/%E8%81%9E%E3%81%8F meaning 1 and 3; "let me listen" I think would use the causative mode.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what you're trying to say.  Do you just want to listen to someone saying their email address? (which sounds a bit odd to me)  Or, do you want them to tell you their email address?  If you want them to *tell* you their email address then the verb you're probably looking for is おしえる not きく

Comment: Also, is your first example question about informing someone that you have a question to ask?  Generally, I believe, that's done by saying something like 聞きたいことがありますが。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to listen? or is it : I would like to ask?

**I would like to ask** is the answer.

> Can you let me listen to what your mail address is? or is it: Is it ok for me to ASK what your mail address is?

**Is it ok for me to ASK what your mail address is?** is the answer.

---

In both cases, 聞く doesn't mean *the speaker wants to "listen"*.
Instead, *the speaker wants to ask (a question)*.

It's safe to say the following are **practically** the same:

- お聞きしたいんですが。
- 教えていただきたいんですが。

---

**EXAMPLES**

聞く = ask (a.k.a 訊く - see bottom of answer)

- メールアドレス聞いていい？
- 道を聞く
- StackExchangeで聞く

聞く = listen (a.k.a 聞く or 聴く - see bottom of answer)

- このCD聞いていい？
- 声を聞く
- Spotifyで聞く

---

**JFYI**

みる (see/watch/look) has *at least* three kanjis - 見る 観る 診る.
きく (hear/listen/ask) has multiple kanjis too - 聞く 聴く 訊く.
You can practically get away with using just 聞く in this day and age. There's a lot of history and politics behind how the usage of kanjis are evolving in Japanese society, so determining which set of kanjis are "correct" is not easy. There are kids, students, adults, elders, grammer nazis, scholars, etc... they all have their preference. Strictly speaking, when you "ask a question", 訊く is probably "correct" kanji. However, 訊く is also excluded from the [list of "commonly used" kanjis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C5%8Dy%C5%8D_kanji) . In reality, this list is just a guideline and most Japanese have experience with the kanji 訊く and know how to read/use it... but when we start writing/typing a message, we simply use 聞く instead of 訊く and most people don't complain.

So the conclusion is, 訊く for asking, 聴く for listening with your heart and soul, and 聞く for listening with your ears...

「メールアドレス、訊いてもいい？」 is "correct" but 聞く can be used to replace all use-cases of 聞く・聴く・訊く, so 「メールアドレス、聞いてもいい？」 works perfectly.

Note that there will be exceptions and it all depends on the time, place, occasion, and people.